# changes() function in python sqlite3 wrapper?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Python's sqlite3 library has a total_changes property on its connection object. However, I would like to know the amount of changes made by my last query, which I would typically query using the sqlite3 changes() function.

Is there a wrapper for that function in the sqlite3 python library?

Comment: Can you just subtract the value of `conn.total_changes` before the transaction from the value after?  That [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.total_changes) wraps, so you might want to handle a negative result.

Answer (score 1):

It's the [rowcount](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount) attribute. As per the docs:

> Read-only attribute that provides the number of modified rows for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and REPLACE statements; is -1 for other statements, including CTE queries. It is only updated by the execute() and executemany() methods, after the statement has run to completion. This means that any resulting rows must be fetched in order for rowcount to be updated.

Found it by looking through all attributes of `Cursor`. No idea why they named `changes` this way, it's quite confusing if you ask me.